# Symfony controller tutorial error

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm following the walk through for learning how to use Symfony (http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_controller.html) however after following through the "Route Parameters" section and going to `localhost/hello/fabien` I receive:

"*404 Not Found The requested URL /hello/fabien was not found on this server.*".

However, I can't see what I'm doing wrong - below is the code I have:

**config.yml**

```
# ...
framework:
        templating:
        {engines: ['twig','php']}
```

**DefaultController:**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
       /** return new Response('Welcome to Symfony!');*/
          return $this->render('default/index.html.twig');
    }


    /**
     * @Route("/hello/{name}", name="hello")
     */
    public function helloAction($name)
    {
        return $this->render('default/hello.html.twig', array(
            'name' => $name
        ));
    }
}
```

**base.html.twig**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
        {% block stylesheets %}{% endblock %}
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}" />
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
        {% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

**hello.html.twig**

```
{# app/Resources/views/default/hello.html.twig #}
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>Hi {{ name }}! Welcome to Symfony!</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Can you run this `php app/console router:debug` and tell us if routes are displayed ?

Comment: have you redirected this url to the url of your symfony project/environment name ? if not the correct url to call is /localhost/prj_dev.php/hello/fabien. 'prj' should be your project name. The _dev part is for development enviroment. Supress it for production.

Comment: No it would be `app_dev.php` in all cases

Comment: Thanks for all the tips - how do I redirect the url to my symfony project/environment name? In the meantime `app_dev.php/hello/fabien` gets me a step closer in that I now get an error message(!): `CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception InvalidArgumentException: "Template name "default/hello.html.twig" is not valid (format is "bundle:section:template.format.engine")." at /home/zac/Test/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 734`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is self explanatory. The code should be like this:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/hello/{name}", name="hello")
 */
public function helloAction($name)
{
    return $this->render('AppBundle:default:hello.html.twig', array(
        'name' => $name
    ));
}
```

or simplified using annotations:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/hello/{name}", name="hello")
 * @Template()
 */
public function helloAction($name)
{
    return array(
        'name' => $name
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Udan, the second doesn't work but guess it's because I'm missing something - I was thinking something along the lines of your first code section but that'd mean the tutorial is wrong? The error I now get is: `CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception InvalidArgumentException: "Unable to find template "AppBundle:default:hello.html.twig"." at /home/zac/Test/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/TwigEngine.php line 128`. However my hello.html.twig is located under `/app/Resources/views/default`

Comment: then that is the issue. @Template() annotation looks for the template in current bundle under Resources/views/<controller name>/<action name>.html.twig

Comment: I've got it working now - thanks for everyone's help. I'm not sure what the problem was in the end but the only clear difference I've made from my original code in the question is updating config.yml to `templating:
        engines: ['twig']`

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just removed {% extends 'mybase.html.twig' %} and run the code it started working and then I again put it at same place and it is working. it seems might be some cache issue. so I request you to clear cache as well.

Thanks
Rikkin